# 3-dimensional jump point search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, geometry, path-finding, a-star

Is there an implementation of three-dimensional (or even D-dimensional) [jump point search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_point_search) algorithm?

Currently I can find only a 2-dimensional one, but I think it possible to formulate the algorithm for higher dimensions.

Comment: 2 votes to close. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but just adding the answer in case someone still needs the answer. [This repository](https://github.com/KumarRobotics/jps3d) contains an implementation for a 2D as well as 3D jps from the MRSL Lab at UPenn.

This paper explains the extension of jump point search to 3D:

> S. Liu, M. Watterson, K. Mohta, K. Sun, S. Bhattacharya, C.J. Taylor and V. Kumar. Planning Dynamically Feasible Trajectories for Quadrotors using Safe Flight Corridors in 3-D Complex Environments. ICRA 2017.

Answer (score 1):

The jump point algorithm is due to Harabor and Grastien's 2011 paper "Online Graph Pruning for Pathfinding on Grid Maps". In this original paper, their abstract says:

> In this paper we present a novel search strategy, specific to grids,    which is fast, optimal and requires no memory overhead.

Their 2012 and 2014 follow-up papers seem similarly restricted.

Using Google Scholar to search citations of the 2011 paper containing the word "three" (as in three-dimensional) did not turn up any promising leads.

So, I'm thinking that there is not a description of a 3+ dimensional jump point search. Your best bet, though, is to drop either Harabor or Grastien a brief, well-worded email asking this same question. If your problem is intriguing enough, perhaps they'll solve the problem and rake up another publication.